# Does PUT or DELETE offer any security advantage over GET or POST?

Tags: http, rest

I have a REST API and I want to handle all HTTP requests via POST.

Is there any security issue in using just POST to perform all CRUD operations requested by a user, which sends JSON specifying the operation to be performed (and other informations)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The `GET` (as well as `HEAD`, `OPTIONS` and `TRACE`) is defined as a *safe method* ([RFC 7231, 4.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)). By this definition you should never use `GET` to replace `PUT`, `DELETE` etc.
- The  `PUT` and `DELETE` are *idempotent methods* ([RFC 7231, 4.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2)):

> A request method is considered "idempotent" if the intended effect
> on the server of multiple identical requests with that method is
> the same as the effect for a single such request. Of the request
> methods defined by this specification, PUT, DELETE, and safe
> request methods are idempotent.

The `POST` method doesn't have these restrictions, but keep in mind that *Representation State Transfer* **REST is a software architechtural style**. From W3C Working Group Note 11 February 2004, [3.1.3](http://3.1.3%20Relationship%20to%20the%20World%20Wide%20Web%20and%20REST%20Architectures), emphasis is mine:

> An even more constrained architectural style for reliable Web
> applications known as *Representation State Transfer* (REST) has been
> proposed by Roy Fielding and has inspired both the W3C Technical
> Architecture Group's architecture document [Web Arch] and many who see
> it as a model for how to build Web services [Fielding]. The REST Web
> is the subset of the WWW (based on HTTP) in which agents provide
> ***uniform interface semantics* -- essentially create, retrieve, update
> and delete -- rather than arbitrary or application-specific
> interfaces**, and manipulate resources only by the exchange of
> representations. Furthermore, the REST interactions are "stateless" in
> the sense that the meaning of a message does not depend on the state
> of the conversation.

Therefore, despite using `POST` in place of `PUT` and `DELETE` doesn't have direct security implications, your API wouldn't be RESTful anymore, but an *arbitrary application-specific interface*.